# Catchable error in php?

Tags: php, class

I have a really odd error:

> [04-Jun-2010 15:55:32] PHP Catchable
>   fatal error:  Object of class Type
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /home/prettykl/public_html/2010/includes/functions.php
>   on line 140

This is the code and line 140 is the $sql line.

```
if (!empty($type)) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `types` WHERE `type` = '$type'";
    $dbi = new db();    
    $result = $dbi->query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $dbi->closeLink();

    $where_array[] = "`typeID` = '".$row->typeID."'";
    $where_array[] = "`typeID2` = '".$row->typeID."'";
}
```

I have 5 or 6 classes and I've never encountered this problem before.
The function has no reference to the classes, any ideas??

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$type` is an object of the class `Type`. You probably want to query a property of that object?

Comment: In addition use print_r($type) to find out what it actually is

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `$type` is actually an object (of class Type), so either the `$type` variable doesn't contain what you expect, or you actually want to get a member of the object instead, so `$type->getSomeString(`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you try to convert an object to string and the object doesn't implement the `__toString()` method. PHP can't handle that conversion. For instance:

```
$s = new stdClass();
echo $s;

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to 
string in php shell code on line 1
```

Note that you are outputting `$type` inside the query, as if it was a string.